# Geometry and Division of Triangles.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Suppose the lengths of the three sides of triangle $ABC$ are 9, 12 and 15 respectively. Divide each side into $n$ ($>=2$) segments of equal length, with $n-1$ division points, and let $S$ be the sum of the square of the distances from each of 3 vertices of triangle $ABC$ to the $n-1$ division points lying on its opposite side.
If $S$ is an integer, find all possible positive integer $n$, with detailed answers.

My solution:

[image: Solution Image for above problem.]

I divided each side into three parts, with two division points each.
The measurement of each division line is : a,b,c,d,e,f.

( $a$ and $b$ are distances to line of size 15,

$c$ and $d$ are distances to line of size 12,

$e$ and $f$ are distances to line of size 9)

Then I get the following equations:

$a^2$+$b^2$=$S$

$c^2$+$d^2$=$S$

$e^2$+$f^2$=$S$

Is there a smarter way to solve this problem?

Please advise.

Comment: A 9:12:15 triangle is right-angled but you have not shown it so. Is that what "not to scale" means?

Comment: From the problem description, shouldn't it be $S = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 +d^2 + e^2 + f^2$ ?

Comment: should i take it as the $n$ = numbers which divide 9,12 and 15 as exact integers, or as exact decimals?

Comment: It's not my question. Apart from $n$ the only mention of an integer value is for $S$. Consider that the sum of say, two fractional values $2/3 + 1/3$ is an integer value, but the components are not.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, what I mean by "not to scale" is that I haven't shown on the diagram that the big triangle is a right-angled triangle.   Also, thank you for pointing out the actual equation for S.

Comment: Considering $n$$=3$, I calculated $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$,$f$ and I got $S$$=700$. ...   but, it will be very tedious to try this method for each integer for $n$$>=2$.   Is there a smarter way to solve this problem?...   Please advise.

Comment: That is probably what the ***real*** problem is. Test cases are usually fairly easy to solve, and this question smells like one from an online "challenge" site such as Project Euler, SPOJ, etc.